# In Umbraco 6 on an ASP masterpage, how do I get an <a> tag to point to a field's "nice URL" as opposed to ID?

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco, umbraco6

At the moment, I have the following code, and it actually mostly works.

```
<a href="<umbraco:Item runat="server" Field="heroLinkNode" />">
    <umbraco:Item runat="server" Field="heroLinkText" />
</a>
```

However, it's creating a URL that looks like `mydomain.com/1234` instead of `mydomain.com/nice-url-of-page`.

P.S. Where would I find documentation for this particular case? My Goolge-foo [led me here](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/templating/masterpages/umbracoitem) but it wasn't too useful.

Comment: In umbraco 7 you could do this `umbraco.library.NiceUrl(NodeId);` is there anything similar in 6? I guess `heroLinkNode` is a custom field too so have you got anything else defined? `heroLinkUrl` for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a few answers on the umbraco forum:
https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/38261-Umbraco-6-New-API-How-do-I-get-a-URL

```
@using Umbraco.Web
@{
    var umbracoHelper = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);
}

@umbracoHelper.NiceUrl(yourId)
```